# Ruby: 'no implicit conversion of nil into String(TypeError) from Zed Shaw's LRTHW

Tags: ruby

Just beginning to learn programming, and starting out with Ruby.  Doing some copy typing exercises from Zed Shaw's *Learn Ruby the Hard Way*

In doing exercise 15 and 16, covering opening files, I run into the same problem when I try to run it.

```
target = open(filename, 'w')
```

I get the message:

> say.rb:10:in `open': no implicit conversion of nil into String
>   (TypeError)   from say.rb:10:in`'

What does this mean? And how do I correct this?

Thanks in advance!

[Direct screen shot from the LRTHW website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL82T.png)

Comment: please provide code at line number 10 in say.rb file

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The above is the code line number 10.  I also put a link on my original post for the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `filename` variable value is not initialized or nil.

```
filename = "path/to/file"
target = open(filename, 'w') if filename.present?
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I posted a link to the code, line 10, that's troubling me.  Zed Shaw, as dogmatic as he is, insist I type the code exactly as posted on his site.  I tried with another exercise also, and it seems that I get a snag again on a similar line.  The above example is from his book, exercise 16, and this one, from exercise 15 gets the same error message on a similar line of code: txt_again = open(file_again).

Answer (score -1):

Everyone: thanks for peering into my question.  I had a friend of mine figure out what the problem was.  I had forgotten that the whole point of the exercise was to use the ARGV,  and that was the missing link, and thus the error.  The first line of code is:  filename = ARGV.first.  When I was running this on the Terminal, I ran it as  >ruby say.rb, without submitting a filename afterwards.  So, on the prompt, I should have submitted it as >ruby say.rb whateverfilename.doc.   So, without that, the program had nothing to chew on.  Thanks again!

Comment: It means my answer is the correct direction for you problem is it?